# What's causing this dip in the FCS curve?

Tags: physical-chemistry, biochemistry, fluorescence

This is a fluorescence correlation spectroscopy measurement of light harvesting complexes. What could be causing the dip at 100 microseconds?
[image: Autocorrelation function of isolated LHCII]

Edit:

The same thing was observed using fluorescence beads.

The only thing I have thought of is a problem reading in photon arrival times, or a problem with the laser.

Comment: It could be a saturation effect. Is it reproducible?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your experimental setup, and ideas about what might be causing this, and what you have changed in an attempt to troubleshoot this.

Comment: @TryHard Saturation of the fluorescence?

Comment: Are you the only person using the device? What is it's prior history and experience of other users? You likely have an instrumental artifact. Perhaps you can look at the raw (uncorrelated) data? The high laser power can cause problems such as saturation. Dips can occur if you have confined diffusion but this seems unlikely and you should be able to discount from the decay or a control such as very different samples.

Comment: http://www.fcsxpert.com/support/assays/troubleshooting.html

Comment: This is the first time FCS has been done on this system. It is normally used for the detection of immobilized molecules. The power used was not enough for saturation in immobilized experiments on the same sample.